# How to match a multidigit number range with Ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm attempting to match a timecode in the format of "0000" to "2459". How can I match numbers in a specific range, so that I could specifically match all numbers between 0 and 24 and all numbers between 0 and 59, and nothing greater or lesser?

I know how to match each individual digit, but that won't do what I want because for example

```
/[0-2][0-4]/
```

would capture numbers 0-4, 10 - 14, and 20-24, missing those in between. So I want to capture all inclusive for multiple digits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
/(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4])[0-5][0-9]/
```

Explanation:

- The `?:` makes the parentheses non-capturing.
- In the parentheses we simply match either 00-19 or 20-24.
- After that we match 00-59.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian's answer fails when `code MOD 10 > 59`. 
For instance, it would not recognize `1080`

Use 
`/(?:[01][0-9][0-9]|2(?:[0-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))[0-9]/` instead,
which takes a 4-digits number beginning either

- with 0 or 1, OR
- with 23, OR
- with 245